# Error uploading video file in php

Tags: php, upload

I want to upload video files using php and the html form, the php code and the error as follows.

I can upload almost any other file type (image, zip, text etc after changing relevant code) except videos (.mp4, .flv, .avi).

UPDATE: I've uploaded the form as an image:
[image]

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="saveVideo.php" method="post" >
 <input type="text" name="txtCardNo" size="6" maxlength="6"autofocus required/>
 <input type="file" name="video" required/>
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="26214400" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ok"/>
```

**saveVideo.php:**

```
require_once('config.php');

// get info from the form 
$card = trim($_POST['txtCardNo']);     //7th line (error 1)

// directory where Videos will be saved 
$target = "videos/"; 
$target = $target . basename($card . ".mp4"); //rename the video
$video = $card . ".mp4"; //name saved in the db

echo $_FILES["video"]["type"];   //14th line (error 2)

if ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/mp4"){ //check for .mp4
    if ($_FILES['video']['size'] > $_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']){ //check file size
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Video size should be less than 25MB.!";
    }else{
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT SN FROM Videos WHERE CardNo = '$card'");  //check for existing image

if (mysql_num_rows($check) < 1){
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO Videos (CardNo, Video, Date) VALUES ('$card', '$video', NOW())";
}else{
            $sql_query = "UPDATE Videos SET CardNo ='$card', Video = '$video', Date = NOW() WHERE CardNo = '$card' LIMIT 1";}
    if(mysql_query($sql_query, $dbLink) or die(mysql_error())){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $target)){ //move video to videos folder
                $_SESSION['error'] =  "The file ". basename( $_FILES['video']['name']). " uploaded successfully.!"; 
            }else {
                $_SESSION['error'] = "Error moving record.!";   }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Error updating record.!"; }}  
}else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid file type. Allowed only .mp4, video format.!";
}  etc..
```

**Error:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: txtCardNo in C:\xampp\htdocs\video\saveVideo.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: video in C:\xampp\htdocs\video\saveVideo.php on line 14
```

I've used the same code (with image attributes) for image upload and it worked perfectly. But when uploading video this gave me lot of errors and some are corrected. Now I can't get the post data from the form in to the saveVideo.php (I checked the 7th and 14th line but no success).

Thanks in advice.

Comment: So? Why isn't txtCardNo defined?

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka That's because you didn't put a blank line before the code block.  A picture will get you downvoted even more because it doesn't help matters.

Comment: I've entered the form in <form></form> tags. But it didn't showed up. Therefore I uploaded the same as an image.

Comment: How can you know that the movie is an mp4 file?

Comment: if ($_FILES["video"]["type"] == "video/mp4"){ //check for .mp4
But the problem here is it does not recognize the txtCardNo and video(post data from the form).

Comment: Please var_dump your post variable: `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: @Daedalus: It shows "array(0) { }". That means nothing sent from the form. Isn't it?

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka Is this on a live server, or your local machine?  I feel like I need to see the bigger picture.

Comment: This is my local machine.

Comment: Win 8, XAMPP 1.7.7, [PHP: 5.3.8] typical installation

Comment: The only thing I can recommend at this point is to upgrade your installation.  I'm unable to replicate your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daedalus for your kind help. I will try that. Before that I am going to re-code the both pages and give a try.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, you should be aware of sql injection attacks.  Your code, as is, does nothing to prevent them. See this for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Daedalus: I upgraded the XAMPP as you suggested and it did the trick. Can you please post your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the life of me, I can't really figure out what's wrong here.  I do have a suggestion though, and that is to upgrade your installation of XAMPP to the latest version.  Usually upgrading fixes whatever bugs are present in the previous install.  I am myself currently running on 1.8.1, and was unable to reproduce your error, so maybe if you upgrade, it will fix whatever was amiss.

Comment: I've installed XAMPP 1.7.7. and didn't word with it. After upgrading to 1.8.1 it just worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka Welcome, glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

What size files you are trying to upload . PHP has certain File Upload size limit. If the uploaded files exceeds this limit, will give blank data from the $_FILES array .
Check your php.ini 's file uploads section for the size limit, also check post max size . By default the size will be 2 MB , you can increase and restart server .

Try this

Comment: This isn't the issue.  Please read the comments next time to see what the issue is.